# Any issues with putting foam around a pex rough in?

Tags: pex, spray-foam

I don't like the idea of drilling the holes required to attach the below cover for the blue pex pipe

The plan is to use silicone or PL to glue the cover to the tiles
I did try to test drill in piece of porcelain using Home Depot drill bits (AvantiPro 4 bit drill set) but they were crap and in one instance they cracked the tile.

So now the plan is to stiffen the PEX in its opening adding some spray foam and then install the cover as indicated above. It I think twice I could even use the foam to stick the cover in place

The idea is to be able to remove it and work behind that tile (a power plug is also there above to the left for the PEX pipe). The tile you see there is attached with caulk (no thin-set) and if it comes to that I should be able to remove it and fix whatever I need behind that tile (the PEX 90 elbow and the wiring for that power plug)

So could foam spray hurt this in any way?

[image]

Comment: a power plug (receptacle?) or any other junction/outlet cannot be concealed by tile.

Comment: it is not. it is installed like anything else I ever have problems with it that I can't think of right now then I have this option to remove that tile easily without breaking it

Comment: spray foam is fine.  it is routinely used to fill wall and ceiling cavities that have pex pipe and to air seal around plumbing that penetrates sill plates.

Answer (score 0):

You can't drill porcelain tile with standard carbide masonry tips. If you use the hammer action on the drill, it'll crack the tile, and if you don't, it'll take forever.

Use a diamond tip, no hammer, and a bit of water for cooling:

[image]

Another option is to just glue the plate to the tile with silicone or MS. If you use foam for that, it will stick everywhere and you'll have a mess to clean.

Comment: How do you think I drilled the existing hole? If you check my other posts here you will see I had a question about glueing things to tiles

Comment: Well I didn't know you drilled them! For this I would use Bostik MS108 or a local equivalent. It's a strong MS caulk/glue. Looks like silicone, but stronger, better adhesion and better tack. Great on tile, too.